# Yii2 разделение прав по атрибутам модели?

Tags: yii2

Есть таблица записей items и модель Item, добавлять записи может как админ, так и простой пользователь, но к примеру админ может добавлять все поля, а пользователь только два, возможно ли разграничить права подобным образом, и если да - то как ?

Answer (score 1):

Да, такое возможно. 
Например через сценарии. В различных сценариях, модель может использовать различные бизнес-правила и логику. Например, атрибут email может потребоваться во время регистрации пользователя, но не во время входа пользователя в систему.

```
// сценарий задается как свойство
$model = new User;
$model->scenario = User::SCENARIO_LOGIN;

// сценарий задается через конфигурацию
$model = new User(['scenario' => User::SCENARIO_LOGIN]);
```

По умолчанию сценарии, поддерживаемые моделью, определяются правилами валидации объявленными в модели.

```
public function rules()
{
return [
    // username, email и password требуются в сценарии "register"
    [['username', 'email', 'password'], 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_REGISTER],

    // username и password требуются в сценарии "login"
    [['username', 'password'], 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_LOGIN],
];
}
```

Взято от сюда https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/structure-models.md#validation-rules

Но в вашем случае готовые Yiiшные валидаторы могут не подйти, тогда можно написать свой, валидатор в виде отдельного класса или простой функции в которой можно произвести проверку текущего юзера на права доступа и если он не Админ, ты вывести сообщение с ошибкой.

Такой пример годится, если вам нужно чтобы обычные пользователи видели поля которые может заполнять админ, но при попытке их заполнить им высветится ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Почитай также про RBAC очень много написано в документации
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html
https://habrahabr.ru/post/235485/

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.